# Bootstrap v2: Does hidden code still load?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, hide, pageload

I'm building a responsive site and I have it set so that when the site is viewed on a mobile phone, I will hide certain code via Bootstrap's "hidden-phone" class. I am using this feature for a heavy slider that I don't to be shown on a mobile phone. But, does the code actually not load or does it load but is not visible? If it does load but does not become visible, I don't see what the point of that is...

Thank you.

Comment: what problem do you have if that code loads?

Comment: it's a huge slider banner that has all kinds of javascript and code that is cpu intensive (only want to run it for desktop resolution). So, if you turn it off with a class but the slider code still loads...what's the point, then, of hiding it?

Comment: Perform a check then to only load the js code if the user is on a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think of replacing your slider with a different element instead of hiding it.
Also,this might help you:

[how to use responsive features of bootstrap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143345/how-to-use-responsive-features-of-bootstrap-2-0)